# TENGO ESTE ERROR AL HACER LA CARGA MASIVA EN SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

buenos días tengo el siguiente error, el problema esta cuando realizo una carga masiva en SQLServer usando BULK INSERT me sale un error indicando...

"Mens. 4860, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 4
No se puede realizar la carga masiva. El archivo 'C:\VENTAS_CRUZIMEX\Enero_Abril_2019' no existe o no tiene derechos de acceso al archivo.

Hora de finalización: 2021-10-13T08:56:28.0660133-04:00"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya hice todo para darle permisos a la carpeta pero aun tengo el problema y no se que mas poder hacer

alguien que pueda ayudarme con este problema, gracias.

Comment: De casualidad: ¿El archivo está en tu equipo?

Comment: si no me equivoco le falta la extensión a archivo de la ruta, que es .xls, .csv, .txt?? el busca un archivo pero al no pasar la extensión no la encuentra

Comment: mmm nunca he visto que no se le ponga la extensión del archivo, por ejemplo `C:\VENTAS_CRUZIMEX\Enero_Abril_2019.csv`

Comment: La razón más probable es que el archivo esté en el cliente y no en el servidor.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/f0cb0e68-c1fd-43f0-a7b7-8bec6e60c262/bulk-insert-desde-archivo-excel?forum=sqlserveres en este enlace de a microsoft colocan la extensión del archivo, ademas indican también que en archivos xls no se puede hacer un bulk insert

Answer (score 0):

2 años y medio después, por si le sirve a alguien más en futuro.
el "Archivo_a_Importasr.csv" tiene que estar en el servidor de SQL.
NO en la pc cliente.